# Vaadin Listbox Option Tooltip

Tags: vaadin

Is it possible to add the title(tooltip) attribute to a listbox ot twincolselect in Vaadin?
I've tried to use setItemCaptionPropertyId() along with setItemCaptionMode() but in vain.

At the end when Vaadin renders the page, the resultant html has only the value attribute to the select component and no title attribute is present.

- Update - my question should have been re-phrased to say - I need tooltip on each individual item (individual row) within a listbox or twinselect.

Comment: please be more precise. do you want to set a caption or a tooltip?

Comment: Tooltip - the native select in HTML has an attribute called TITLE. Is there any way to populate that attribute in Vaadin? I'm aware that caption is what's visible in a ListBox, but what if I have a really long item and the text is half hidden, is it possible to display a tooltip or a span when I hover.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for Nativeselect component

```
// Create the selection component
final NativeSelect mynativeselect= new NativeSelect("myLabel");

// Add some items
for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
    mynativeselect.addItem(i);
}
//set tooltip
mynativeselect.setDescription("My tooltip");
```

Comment: Thanks. But this provide a tooltip on the listbox not the individual items in the list. What I need is a tool tip on the individual items so that when we have long items, users can understand what the item is from the tool tip.